# Difference between Events,Listeners and Observers?

Tags: laravel, frameworks, event-listener, laravel-9, observers

I confused this Events,Listeners and observers in laravel

Comment: Events get dispatched, listeners listen for dispatched events and observers are listeners but specifically listening for Eloquent model events

Comment: For further reading: [Publish-Subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) (Publishers here are event creators and subscribers are event listeners, or observers) as well as [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) where the observer is a special case of subscriber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observers and events do not behave at all like each other

Observers are basically predefined events that happen only on Eloquent Models (creating a record, updating a record, deleting, etc). Events are generic, aren't predefined, and can be used anywhere, not just in models.

Observers:

An observer watches for specific things that happen within eloquent such as saving, saved, deleting, deleted (there are more but you should get the point). Observers are specifically bound to a model.

Events:

Events are actions that are driven by whatever the programmer wants. If you want to fire an event when somebody loads a page, you can do that. Unlike observers events can also be queue, and ran via laravel's cron heartbeat. Events are programmer defined effectively. They give you the ability to handle actions that you would not want a user to wait for (example being the purchase of a pod cast)

The documentation does a very good job covering these.

Reference Taken From : https://www.scratchcode.io/laravel/difference-between-events-and-observers-in-laravel/

Comment: As @apokryfos said in comment to OP, observers are more listeners than events.